# Kotlin generic bounds for Class

Tags: generics, kotlin

The following generics doesn't compile. What is semantically wrong here?

**Function call**

```
start(MainActivity.javaClass) // <== Doesn't compile
```

**Method Definition**

```
// Definition
public fun <T : Activity> start(activityClass: Class<T>) {
    startActivity(Intent(this, activityClass))
}
```

**Compiler Error**

```
Error:(43, 9) Type parameter bound for T in fun <T : android.app.Activity> 
start(activityClass: java.lang.Class<T>): kotlin.Unit is not satisfied:  
inferred type com.mobsandgeeks.hellokotlin.MainActivity.
<class-object-for-MainActivity> is not a subtype of android.app.Activity
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`javaClass` has been deprecated. Use this instead:

```
val i = Intent(this@Activity, Activity::class.java)
startActivity(i)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `javaClass<MainActivity>()` instead of `MainActivity.javaClass`

Comment: Thanks, that worked. What genetic type parameter should I use if I want to pass in MainActivity.javaClass?

Comment: If you mean the analog of Java's `MainActivity.class`, then use `javaClass<MainActivity>()` in Kotlin

Comment: Andrey, that's right. I meant to ask, how to change the function signature for the above mentioned code to compile?

Comment: You could remove the `: Activity` bound from `T`, but then you are passing the class object of `MainActivity` to `Intent`, so it must be a component capable of handling this intent.

Comment: To clarify: a class and its class object are not related by inheritance or any other type-like relation. A class object is associated with a class for convenience only, so I don't think it makes sense to pass a class object to `start()`

Comment: This syntax has changed in current Kotlin, can you please update the answer to `MainActivity:class.java`

Answer (score 3):

Another option:

```
inline public fun <reified T : Activity> start() {
    startActivity(Intent(this, javaClass<T>()))
}
start<MainActivity>()
```

Comment: I like this better and I'm going to use this +1. However Andrey's answer is more relevant to my question.

Comment: Yes, thats right. This answer is just a "nicier" option

Comment: or you can use `intentFor<MyActivity>()` , if you are using anko, basically it's the same thing

Comment: This syntax has changed in current Kotlin, can you please update the answer using `javaClass<T>` to `T::class.java`

Answer (score 2):

The only way it worked for me is doing this:

```
val intent = Intent(this, NextActivity::class.java)
startActivity(intent)
```

None of the other solutions have worked, including the usage of `javaClass`